# How to parse text within span tags using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to build an application displaying artists from a popular venue and want to extract only the artist's name.

Here is my code:

```
data.css('.headliner').each do |artist|
puts artist
end
```

It's currently returning:

```
<span class="headliner"><span class="prepend"><i>Rescheduled Date</i></span><br>London Grammar</span>
<span class="headliner">Hozier</span>
<span class="headliner"><span class="prepend"><i>KFOG presents</i></span><br>Ben Howard<br><span class="append"><i>with special guest</i><br></span></span>
<span class="headliner">Dr. Dog</span>
```

Some elements have more than one `span` tag and I'm having trouble getting the data I want. All I want returned is the artist's name such as 'London Grammar', 'Hozier', 'Ben Howard', and 'Dr. Dog'.

Currently, when I run `artist.text` it returns "Rescheduled DateLondon Grammar" and so on.

---

```html
<table class="concert_calendar" cellspacing="0" width="720" style="margin-top:35px;">
    <tbody><tr><td class="noborder"><img src="images/title_date2.gif" alt="Date"></td>
     <td class="noborder" colspan="2"><img src="images/title_show2.gif" alt="Show"></td>
        <td class="noborder"><img src="images/title_time2.gif" alt="Time"></td>
        <td class="noborder"><img src="images/title_tickets2.gif" alt="Tickets"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="5" class="noborder"><hr size="1" color="#550818" noshade="" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;"></td></tr>
  <tr><td style="width:100px;" class="">Saturday,<br>February 7</td>
     <td style="width:115px;" valign="top" class=""><a href="popartist.php?cID=4600&amp;KeepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=600&amp;width=475" class="con_img thickbox"><img src="http://www.apeconcerts.com/concertimages/LondonGrammar_100.jpg" alt="London Grammar"></a></td>
        <td valign="top" style="width:345px; padding-right:10px;" class="">
         <a href="popartist.php?cID=4600&amp;KeepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=600&amp;width=475" style="text-decoration:none;" class="thickbox">
             <span class="headliner"><span class="prepend"><i>Rescheduled Date</i></span><br>London Grammar</span></a>
         <div><span class="warmup">Until The Ribbon Breaks</span><br>
            <span class="warmup"></span></div></td>
        <td style="width:80px;">show<br>8:00PM</td>
        <td style="width:80px;">
        <img src="images/cal_soldout.gif" alt="SOLD OUT - Thank you!">        </td></tr>
  <tr><td style="width:100px;">Tuesday,<br>February 10</td>
     <td style="width:115px;" valign="top"><a href="popartist.php?cID=4733&amp;KeepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=600&amp;width=475" class="con_img thickbox"><img src="http://www.apeconcerts.com/concertimages/Hozier_1001.jpg" alt="Hozier"></a></td>
        <td valign="top" style="width:345px; padding-right:10px;" class="">
         <a href="popartist.php?cID=4733&amp;KeepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=600&amp;width=475" style="text-decoration:none;" class="thickbox">
             <span class="headliner">Hozier</span></a>
         <div class=""><span class="warmup">Ásgeir</span><br>
            <span class="warmup"></span></div></td>
        <td style="width:80px;">show<br>8:00PM</td>
        <td style="width:80px;">
        <img src="images/cal_soldout.gif" alt="SOLD OUT - Thank you!">        </td></tr>
```

Comment: Are you about the `HTML` you want to extract the data from; it appears extremely irregular. All three names seem to have different formatting albeit being in similar span. I wonder if the page is hand coded: http://pastebin.com/T382rEX5

Comment: Yeah, I had the same thoughts. The inconsistency in formatting is seen throughout the HTML which is why I'm unsure how to parse through the spans.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is a continuous requirement to automate, but if not it can be considered to be dealt with some string operations too. Any chance you can share the `HTML`?

Comment: We need to see a minimal sample of your input HTML. Without it we're shooting in the dark.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've posted a snippet of the HTML below.

Answer (score 2):

> All I want returned is the artist's name such as 'London Grammar',
>   'Hozier', 'Ben Howard', and 'Dr. Dog'

Here's one way:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = %q{
<span class="headliner"><span class="prepend"><i>Rescheduled Date</i></span><br>London Grammar</span>
<span class="headliner">Hozier</span>
<span class="headliner"><span class="prepend"><i>KFOG presents</i></span><br>Ben Howard<br><span class="append"><i>with special guest</i><br></span></span>
<span class="headliner">Dr. Dog</span>
}

html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
headliners = html_doc.css('.headliner')

headliners.each do |headliner|
  headliner.css('i').each do |i|
    i.content = ''
  end

  puts headliner.text
end

--output:--
London Grammar
Hozier
Ben Howard
Dr. Dog
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you're trying to do is remove the `<i>` tag's content, then just remove the tags entirely:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<span class="headliner"><span class="prepend"><i>Rescheduled Date</i></span><br>London Grammar</span>
<span class="headliner">Hozier</span>
<span class="headliner"><span class="prepend"><i>KFOG presents</i></span><br>Ben Howard<br><span class="append"><i>with special guest</i><br></span></span>
<span class="headliner">Dr. Dog</span>
EOT

doc.search('.headliner i').map(&:remove)
puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >> <span class="headliner"><span class="prepend"></span><br>London Grammar</span>
# >> <span class="headliner">Hozier</span>
# >> <span class="headliner"><span class="prepend"></span><br>Ben Howard<br><span class="append"><br></span></span>
# >> <span class="headliner">Dr. Dog</span>
# >> </body></html>
```

At that point it's really easy to iterate over the `.headliner` tags and output their content:

```
puts doc.search('.headliner').map(&:text)

# >> London Grammar
# >> Hozier
# >> Ben Howard
# >> Dr. Dog
```

I'd probably do it a little different for a big page consisting of a lot of tags matching `.headliner` but this is sufficient for normal pages.

See "[How to avoid joining all text from Nodes when scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594656/how-to-avoid-joining-all-text-from-nodes-when-scraping)" also.